# Spring Cloud Config client - how to debug?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

After upgrading Spring Cloud libraries to newest version Spring Cloud Config client behaves differently in terms of logging.
In previous version, whenever Spring Cloud Config server was unavailable, I could see log:

```
 Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888/. Will be trying the next url if available
```

Currently there's no logs, application simply hangs. After Config Server is available, app also starts an emits all logs at once. It looks like it's caching somehow all logs istead of outputting it immediately.

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.4:run (default-cli) @ gateway-service ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
2021-10-07 18:37:02,746 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [entityId]
2021-10-07 18:37:02,747 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [entityId] starting at position 146 in conversion pattern.
2021-10-07 18:38:36,172 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [entityId]
2021-10-07 18:38:36,172 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [entityId] starting at position 147 in conversion pattern.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.4)

2021-10-07 18:38:36.340  INFO 80607 --- [           main] c.y.g.GatewayApplication                 [%entityId] : Starting GatewayApplication using Java 11.0.12 on ...
```

In the example above, I was waiting for 30s, before starting Config Server (see timestamps). What is wrong?